# New domain controller for Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

I've been forcefully (replaced old IT) tasked to create new AD with new domain name.
Current setup is *something.local* with connector to AAD where users are logging in as *user@domain.tld*.

I've been tasked to create completely new domain with domain name "domain.tld" and they want me to sync this new domain to current AAD (where users will still log in as *user@domain.tld*) (to keep data in groups for teams etc.)

I don't care about personal OneDrives since users never really used them, and I can reassign users to groups manually.

**Edit**
Is it even possible to sync this new AD without breaking everything apart? Or do I have to delete everything and start all over again?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @TomW Sorry Edited

Comment: Maybe this is more a question for [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: How is `domain.tld` a 'completely new domain' if users are currently logging in to it on the existing AAD tenant?

Comment: Related; if you already have an AAD directory, why do you need to create another one?